# JQuery Add Class every 6 LI's

Tags: jquery

I seem to be having a problem with this jquery code.

I want to add a class to the 1st and then every 6

's... I'm getting the 1st and the 6th but on the third one round it's doing the 11th instead on the 12th.

```
Here is the code:Query:

$('ul li:nth-child(5n+1)').addClass("red").text("Here");

Here is the css:

li { background-color:blue; }
.red{ background-color: red; }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$('ul li:first, ul li:nth-child(6n)').addClass("red").text("Here");
```